# Issue regarding code security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, code-security

I have an existing ruby on rails application and one of our client want to set our application on premise using a server. Now I am bit worried about the code security and anti-theft issues. Is there any way out so that the application code will remain on the server and will run smoothly and at the same time no one will be able to copy the application code.

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

In short, this can be possible only if you will be able to lock server access. Otherwise the 3rd party has access to the sources and most likely the application's database.